# Do all diagonalisable matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So. Let us label right-eigenvectors of $M$ as $|\lambda\rangle$ and left-eigenvectors of $M$ as $\langle\lambda|$. That is,
\begin{gather}
M |\lambda\rangle = \lambda |\lambda\rangle \text{ and } \langle\lambda| M = \langle\lambda| \lambda .
\end{gather}
This makes sense (I hazard) because a left-eigenvector is adjoint, which doesn't have to mean ‘conjugate transpose’, to a right-eigenvector via a shared eigenvalue. Now, we may write
\begin{gather}
M|\lambda\rangle = \lambda |\lambda\rangle \text{ and } \langle\mu| M = \langle\mu| \mu ,
\end{gather}
which implies that both
\begin{gather}
\langle \mu | M | \lambda \rangle = \lambda \langle \mu | \lambda \rangle \text{ and } \langle \mu | M | \lambda \rangle = \mu \langle \mu | \lambda \rangle
\end{gather}
which immediately implies, upon the assumption that
\begin{gather}
\lambda \neq \mu ,
\end{gather}
that
\begin{gather}
\langle\mu|\lambda\rangle = 0 .
\end{gather}
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Left and right eigenvectors are biorthogonal, that's what you showed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, but to a different question: Do all diagonalizable matrices have *biorthogonal* right and left eigenvectors?

To see this, let the matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be diagonalizable so that there exists a nonsingular matrix $X=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and diagonal $\Lambda=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ such that 
$$A=X\Lambda X^{-1}.$$

A nonzero vector $x$ is called right eigenvector of $A$ (associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda$), if $Ax=\lambda x$ for some scalar $\lambda$. A nonzero vector $y$ is called left eigenvector (associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda$), if $y^*A=\lambda y^*$ for some scalar $\lambda$ (or equivalently, $A^*y=\bar{\lambda} y$).

The columns $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of the matrix $X$ above are the right eigenvectors of $A$. To see this, post-multiply $A=X\Lambda X^{-1}$ by $X$ to get $AX=X\Lambda$ and look on each column of the matrix equation, which states that $Ax_i=\lambda_ix_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

We have also that $X^{-1}A=\Lambda X^{-1}$ (simply pre-multiplying $A=X\Lambda X^{-1}$ by $X^{-1}$), that is, $Y^*A=\Lambda Y^*$ with $Y=[y_1,\ldots,y_n]=(X^{-1})^*$. The columns $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ of $Y$ are the left eigenvectors of $A$. To see that, look on the rows of $Y^*A=\Lambda Y^*$: $y^*_iA=\lambda_i y_i^*$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

The right eigenvectors $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and left eigenvectors $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are *biorthogonal*, that is, $y_i^*x_j=\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol. This can be easily verified using the relation between $X$ and $Y$, because $y_i^*x_j=\delta_{ij}$ iff $Y^*X=I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix) and $Y^*X=((X^{-1})^*)^*X=X^{-1}X=I$.

P.S.: Sorry for not using your notation :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is a great help.

I had a quick question: is there an obvious way to normalise left- and right-eigenvectors separately?

PS: I chose bra-ket notation because it reduced the number of symbols in the question. But I think bra-ket notation is actually what confused me!

Comment: Well, you can normalize them separately (say, to have unit norm). Then, however, you have only $y_i^*x_j=0$ if and only if $i\neq j$. Generally $y_i^*x_i$ won't be 1 but some other (nonzero) number dependent on $i$. This corresponds to replacing $X$ and $Y$ by $\tilde{X}=XD_X$ and $\tilde{Y}=YD_Y$, where $D_{\cdot}$ are nonsingular diagonal matrices. Then $\tilde{Y}^*\tilde{X}=D_YD_X$.

Comment: Anyway, there's nothing wrong on your statement that right and left eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. The matrix even does not need to be diagonalizable.

Comment: But the matrix does have to be diagonalisable if we want an eigenbasis to exist, no?

Comment: Of course, if the matrix is diagonalisable then the eigenvectors (both left and right) are basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. That does not mean that a matrix, which is not diagonalisable, cannot have (some) left and right eigenvectors, which are still biorthogonal.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Do you happen to know if biorthogonality holds for not diagonalisable matrices? In other words, is it guaranteed that the corresponding left and right eigenvectors are not orthogonal, $y_i^*x_i\neq0$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no: define $T:R^2→R^2$ by $T(1,0)=(1,0)$, $T(1,1)=(2,2)$. Then $T$ is diagonalizable, and the eigenvalues are even distinct, but not in an orthonormal basis, ie. $T$ is not self adjoint. The problem with what you have done is that you have implicitly assumed $M$ is self adjoint, since for self adjoint operators, $⟨μ|M≡(M|μ⟩)^∗$. What does $⟨u|M$ mean if $M$ is not self adjoint?

Comment: $\langle u | M$ means exactly that. And $\langle u | M = \langle u | u$ means $\langle u |$ is a left-eigenvector of $M$. Can I not take a single matrix $M$ and compose left- and right-eigenvectors? Somehow I have a misunderstanding of the relation of left-eigenvectors to right-eigenvectors, which is what I would like to clarify.

Comment: $\langle u|M$ is an operator, and as usual is defined by how it operates on kets. If you already have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors then since $\langle u|M|\lambda\rangle=\langle u|(M|\lambda\rangle)=\lambda\langle u|\lambda\rangle=0$ if $\lambda\ne u, =u$ if $\lambda=u$, you can just identify $\langle u|M$ with $u\langle u|$ but otherwise it may not make sense to make that identification.

Comment: Okay, so I take $M$ and in the usual way diagonalise, or find a set of (right-)eigenvectors, by solving $M | \lambda \rangle = \lambda | \lambda \rangle$. Then I define the left eigenvectors as the $\langle\lambda|$ such that $\langle\lambda| M |\lambda\rangle = \lambda$. Then what goes wrong with my original question? I must apologise for the somewhat trivial question; I post because I know there is something I am very confused about.

Comment: That definition doesn't make sense though. What would $\langle\lambda|u\rangle$ be?

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, let me think for a bit; I'll get back in a bit. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just think about how $\langle u|M$ is defined:  $(\langle u|M)|\lambda\rangle \equiv \langle u|(M|\lambda\rangle)$. Quantum mechanics notation is great, but you have to be careful when using it with generality.

Comment: IMHO there's nothing wrong with the statement if, in the title, "orthogonal" is replaced by "biorthogonal" and "eigenvectors" by "right and left eigenvectors".

Comment: And so you(?) down voted me for giving a correct answer to the correct question, but not a correct answer to the wrong question? (or was it not you?)

Comment: @JLA: Well, I'm sorry for the drama my "opinion" is apparently making here :-D I reckon on MSE that OP's may have some problems expressing clearly their thoughts, in particular, by improper titles of their questions. Consequently, people answering their questions sometimes take the opportunity (for free reputation or whatever it is called here) to provide rather trivial answers to the questions the OP's apparently did not mean to ask for. In my opinion, a good mathematician should read the question body as well and, if possible, deduce the right question the OP was asking for.

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel You are seriously abusing the voting system. I don't think what the OP meant to ask was at all what you said. The question was very clear: do all diagonalizable matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors? I unequivocally answered the question.  And how is what I said a "trivial answer"? The OP even said that what I said was useful. It's not your job to rewrite the question for the OP and be a dictator.

Comment: @JLA I do not rewrite questions, I certainly don't feel like a dictator, and certainly I'm sorry the democratic expression of my opinion is causing you such troubles.

Comment: Unfortunately you are being rather undemocratic by downvoting answers that clearly explain to the OP and others who use this notation why they are confused in the first place, on top of telling the OP what they meant.